# Where the compiler find ``printf``?

Tags: c++, c

I haven't touched on c++ for a while and this question might be stupid but it indeed bothers me for a while.

Suppose I have the following c program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int i;
  for(i=0; i<10; i++)
  {
    printf("Hello World!\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I know the reason I include `stdio.h` is because I call `printf` in `main` but I'm wondering how compiler would know where to find the implementation of `printf()` during the compilation? `stdio.h` only provides function prototype but what exactly is happening during the compilation?

Will there be certain prefixed path that compiler knows to search for the implementation of `printf`? If so, how to find them?

Thanks much!

Comment: It's the linker that actually finds it. And yes the path to find the standard libraries is predefined.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Could you please explain a little bit more? Thanks!

Comment: [Here's some more info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23181905/standard-c-library-linking)

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Thanks for the link. However, that question seems partially answers my question. I'm more interested in the path finding during link stage.

Comment: Compiling basically turns a .c (or .cpp) file into a .o file.  The .o files are combined, along with any needed library searches, to produce an executable.  If file `foo.c` defines a function `foo`, and `bar.c` defines a function `bar`, then `foo.o` and `bar.o` contain compiled versions of those functions.  It's only when the object files are linked that external references are resolved, and that's when libraries are searched.  The final executable should contain no unresolved references.

Comment: "path finding during link stage" It is different for different compilers, or for different versions of the same compiler. Why are you interested in it?

Comment: @n.m. Trying to have a more clear picture about the compilation of a c program. I want to gain more insight on the background of using standard c library instead of always treating them as a black box.

Comment: You're supposed to view them as a black box. That's why it's so enigmatic and mystical and varying between compilers. I'm sure you know, functions which arent in the standard library are following entirely different rules.

Comment: C or C++? Probably worth being straight on the language you use.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11481258/12711 if you want to really know what's happening behind the scenes of where the compiler/linker are looking for headers and libraries (at least for gcc).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Chances are if you're on a linux system, the C library used is `glibc`. GCC doesn't actually provide a C library implementation, only the header files. It's the job of the C library to actually *implement* the definition of these functions. On Linux, there's something called "shared libraries" which are loaded dynamically by programs that need it. For example:

```
ldd /usr/bin/gcc
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd9e9f8000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007ff9a35a6000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff9a31de000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055953c573000)
```

You can disable the linking of `libc` by passing `-nostdlib` and link in your own C library. There are also other ways to replace definitions provided by the C library, like linking in your own `malloc` and so on. The linker is only allowed to find *one* definition for any given declaration and since there is no name mangling in C, it's easy to do so.

<sup>This is an oversimplified explanation, and doesn't mention builtins, the math library or the like.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

`printf` is part of standard library, which is called "standard" because it is linked by default by C compiler. Standard library is typically provided by operating system or compiler. On most linux systems, it is located in `libc.so`, whereas on MS Windows C Library is provided by Visual C runtime file `msvcrt.dll`.

Answer (score 3):

After some digging, the following explanation makes the most sense to me:

**short version**

a           header           file           contains           declarations           that           the           compiler           needs,           but           not           implementations.                   The
corresponding          library          file          has          those.                The          compiler          needs          the          header          files          but          not          the          libraries;           the          linker
needs        the        libraries,        not        the        header        files.

**long version**

The header file does not contain the definition of the `printf()`
 function (i.e., its implementation.)  That is contained in the C Standard I/O Library (i.e., `glibc`). The compiler is not able to    create        the        machine        instructions        that
will       cause       the
`printf()`
function       to       run,        because       it       does       not       know       where         the
`printf()`
implementation       is;
it        cannot        create        a        call          to        this        function.            Instead,        the        compiler        places        a        notation        in        the        executable        file        that
says,        more        or        less,        the        call        to
`printf()`
must        be        resolved        by        the        linker.

The       linker       is       a       separate       program       that       runs       after       the       compiler.          It       looks       at       all       of       the       unresolved       symbols       in       the
program,        such        as
`printf()`
,        and        tries        to        resolve        them        by        looking        up        their        locations        in        the        software        libraries
that       the       program       needs.          In       this       case,       the       linker       needs       to       look       up       in       the       C       Standard       I/O       Library       the       location
of         the
`printf()`
function,         so         that         it         can         patch         the         code         to         make         a         call         to         it (`ldd /usr/bin/gcc` way or `gcc -v foo.c -Wl --verbose` way).             The         C         Standard         I/O         Library
is         special         because         it         is         used         in         almost         every         C         program,         and         therefore         many         C         implementations         include         it
within        the        C        runtime        library.           This        makes        it        possible        for        the        linker        to        find        it        easily